# How to view the Folder and Files in GAC?

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, gac

I want to view the folders and sub folders in [GAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache). Also want to know about adding and removing from [GAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache).

To install we write this lines in command prompt by opening  `Visual Studio command prompt`:-

`gacutil /i [assembly path]`

But to uninstall we need only:-

`gacutil /u [assembly name]`

Why?

Comment: If you go to one of the assembly folders in the Windows directory, then type a dll name you're looking for in the search bar (of file explorer), they should start showing up.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Install:

```
gacutil -i "path_to_the_assembly"
```

View:

Open in Windows Explorer folder

- .NET 1.0 - NET 3.5: `c:\windows\assembly` (`%systemroot%\assembly`)
- .NET 4.x: `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly`

OR `gacutil –l`

When you are going to install an assembly you have to specify where `gacutil` can find it, so you have to provide a full path as well. But when an assembly already is in GAC - `gacutil` know a folder path so it just need an assembly name.

MSDN:

- [How to: Install an Assembly into the Global Assembly Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79.aspx)
- [How to: View the Contents of the Global Assembly Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9x295t9k.aspx)

Comment: Note that for .NET 4.0 the GAC location is now:
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\

Answer (score 65):

I'm a day late and a dollar short on this one. If you want to view the folder structure of the GAC in Windows Explorer, you can do this by [using the registry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jigarme/archive/2007/06/20/want-to-see-assembly-in-its-naked-view.aspx):

1. Launch regedit.
2. Navigate to HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion
3. Add a DWORD called DisableCacheViewer and set the value to 1.

For a temporary view, you can substitute a drive for the folder path, which strips away the special directory properties.

1. Launch a Command Prompt at your *account's* privilege level.

   - If you elevate your privileges, [you might not see the drive in Windows 7](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/is-the-subst-command-broken-in-windows-7/4855524d-a28b-403e-8d7e-515926e01aaa).
2. Type SUBST Z: C:\Windows\assembly

   - Z can be any free drive letter.
3. Open My Computer and look in the new substitute directory.
4. To remove the virtual drive from Command Prompt, type SUBST Z: /D

As for why you'd want to do something like this, I've used this trick to compare GAC'd DLLs between different machines to make sure they're truly the same.

Comment: You can automate editing the registry with Powershell:

Comment: New-Item 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Fusion' -Force | New-ItemProperty -Name "DisableCacheViewer" -PropertyType DWord -Value 1 -Force | Out-Null

Comment: To expand on your instructions (for us dummys):  1. Launch regedit   2. Navigate to Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion   3. Right-click on the right side and select "New" ... "DWORD (32-bit) value"   4. Call it "DisableCacheViewer"  5. Right click the new entry "DisableCacheViewer" and select "Modify..."  6. Set the "data value" to 1.  (Set it back to 0 to undo it.)

Answer (score 46):

Launch the program "Run" (Windows Vista/7/8: type it in the start menu search bar) and type: 
`C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL`

Then move to the parent folder (Windows Vista/7/8: by clicking on it in the explorer bar) to see all the GAC files in a normal explorer window. You can now copy, add and remove files as everywhere else.

Comment: Thank you - it allowed me to use Windows Explorer which was marked obsolete since .NET 4

Answer (score 9):

To view the files just browse them from the command prompt (`cmd`), eg.:

```
c:\>cd \Windows\assembly\GAC_32
c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32> dir
```

To add and remove files from the GAC use the tool [`gacutil`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: i want to view it as normal folder.

Comment: @CodingMastero It is ***NOT*** a normal folder!

Comment: Cant we use some hack to view it as a normal one?

Comment: @CodingMastero No you cannot. You can view it through the command prompt as stated above.

Comment: Well for .NET 4.0 you can view it as a normal folder in Explorer, because there is no longer a shell extension that hides the physical layout. **However**, just asking for the possibility to do that worries me. :-)

Comment: @Christian.K I agree with the latter, and am puzzled by the former. Shell extensions are pertinent to the OS and not the framework version. I have .Net4.0 installed on my Win7 machine, and I cannot browse `c:\Windows\assembly` as a normal folder.

Comment: Yes. Sorry I may not have been clear here. You cannot use `C:\Windows\assembly` to browse the .NET 4.0 GAC. Of course you can still use it with .NET 2/3 (if that is installed as well). There is no comparable shell extensions (AFAIK) that works in the same way for the new `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly` directory.

Comment: @KlausByskovPedersen Actually, you can view it as a normal folder.  See my answer for two methods of doing it.

Comment: @RohitVipinMathews If you really want to see the "C:\Windows\assembly" folder as a normal folder in Windows Explorer you can rename / delete the file Desktop.ini:
`Start CMD.EXE as Admin` 
`CD /D C:\Windows\assembly` 
`ATTRIB -H -S Desktop.ini` 
`REN Desktop.ini Desktop.ini-DISABLED`

Then (close and) reopen the explorer window.

Answer (score 7):

You install as assemblies by using:

- A setup program, that you author for your application.
- Using the `gacutil.exe` tool with the `-i` option from the command line.
- Dropping the assembly in `%windir%\Assembly` (only up to .NET 3.5, CLR 2.0)

You view the content of the GAC using:

- The `gacutil.exe` tool with the `-l` option.
- For .NET 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5 (CLR 2.0) browsing to `%windir%\assembly` using the Windows Explorer.

Note that the (physical) GAC location has changed for .NET 4.0. It is no longer in `%windir%\Assembly`, but now in `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly`. However, you should never write any code that depends on the physical location anyway, because given the tools available that is hardly necessary (some "cool" homegrown system diagnostics tools aside).

Comment: Besides `gacutil.exe` the only other tool available that I'm aware of is fusion.dll.